# optimize query (2 simple left joins)

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT fcat.id,fcat.title,fcat.description, 
count(DISTINCT ftopic.id) as number_topics, 
count(DISTINCT fpost.id) as number_posts FROM fcat 
LEFT JOIN ftopic ON fcat.id=ftopic.cat_id 
LEFT JOIN fpost ON ftopic.id=fpost.topic_id 
GROUP BY fcat.id
ORDER BY fcat.ord
LIMIT 100;
```

index on ftopic_cat_id, fpost.topic_id, fcat.ord

EXPLAIN:

```
id      select_type     table   type    possible_keys       key         key_len     ref             rows    Extra
1       SIMPLE          fcat    ALL     PRIMARY             NULL        NULL        NULL            11      Using temporary; Using filesort
1       SIMPLE          ftopic  ref     PRIMARY,cat_id_2    cat_id_2    4           bloki.fcat.id   72   
1       SIMPLE          fpost   ref     topic_id_2          topic_id_2  4           bloki.ftopic.id 245
```

fcat - 11 rows,
ftopic - 1106 rows,
fpost - 363000 rows

Query takes 4,2 sec

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fcat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(250) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `ord` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ord` (`ord`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ftopic` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastname` varchar(200) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `closed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `cat_id_2` (`cat_id`,`updated`,`visible`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1116 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fpost` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `imageName` varchar(300) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `md5` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
  KEY `topic_id_2` (`topic_id`,`created`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=390971 ;
```

Thanks,
hamlet

Comment: please also post the tables' create statements so people can see indexes and column types.

Comment: I think since both `ftopic.id` and `fpost.id` are primary keys, they are unique, which means you can drop the `DISTINCT` when counting them (because you group by fcat.id - each category has many posts but a post can't appear under the same category twice - so no duplications, right?). I am not sure it will significantly affect performance but worth a try...

Comment: yes, DISTINCT was there just to be safe, removing them doesn't help

Comment: If there's 11 rows to consider it doesn't make sense for MySQL to go to the index, so it doesn't. Increase the size of the table and MySQL should start using the index.

Comment: Updated my answer to give you more background, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a key with both `fcat.id, fcat.ord`

Comment: Tried that: KEY `id` (`id`,`ord`) - this index isn't used

Comment: Seems strange its showing only rows, 11, 72, 245 and taking 4.2seconds? yeah that should be very quick

Comment: `Using temporary; Using filesort` - is it sorting all the posts or why?

Answer (score 0):

**Bold rewrite**

This code is not functionally identical, but...

Because you want to know about `distinct` ftopic.id and fpost.id I'm going to be bold and suggest two INNER JOIN's instead of LEFT JOIN's.
Then because the two id's are autoincrementing they will no longer repeat, so you can drop the `distinct`.

```
SELECT 
  fcat.id
  , fcat.title
  , fcat.description
  , count(ftopic.id) as number_topics
  , count(fpost.id) as number_posts 
FROM fcat 
INNER JOIN ftopic ON fcat.id = ftopic.cat_id 
INNER JOIN fpost ON ftopic.id = fpost.topic_id 
GROUP BY fcat.id
ORDER BY fcat.ord
LIMIT 100;
```

It depends on your data if this is what you are looking for, but I'm guessing it will be faster.

All your indexes seem to be in order though.

**MySQL does not use indexes for small sample sizes!**
Note that the `explain` list that MySQL only has **11 rows** to consider for fcat. This is not enough for MySQL to really start worrying about indexes, so it doesn't.
Because going to the index for small row-counts slows things down.

MySQL is trying to speed things up so it chooses not to use the index, this confuses a lot of people because we are trained so hard on the index.  Small sample sizes don't give good explains!

Increase the size of the test data so MySQL has more rows to consider and you should start seeing the index being used.

**Common misconceptions about `force index`**
`Force index` does **not** force MySQL to use an index as such.
It hints at MySQL to use a **different** index from the one it might naturally use **and** it pushes MySQL into using an index by setting a very high cost on a table scan.
*(In your case MySQL is **not** using a table scan, so `force index` has no effect)*

MySQL (same most other DBMS's on the planet) has a very strong urge to use indexes, so if it doesn't (use any) that's because using no index at all is faster.

**How does MySQL know which index to use**
One of the parameters the query optimizer uses is the stored cardinality of the indexes.
Over time these values change... But studying the table takes time, so MySQL doesn't do that unless you tell it to.
Another parameter that affects index selection is the predicted disk-seek-times that MySQL expects to encounter when performing the query.

**Tips to improve index usage**

1. `ANALYZE TABLE` will instruct MySQL to re-evaluate the indexes and update its key distribution (cardinality). *(consider running it daily/weekly in a cron job)*
2. `SHOW INDEX FROM table` will display the key distribution.
3. MyISAM tables and indexes fragment over time. Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to unfragment  the tables and recreate the indexes.
4. `FORCE/USE/IGNORE INDEX` limits the options MySQL's query optimizer has to perform your query. Only consider it on complex queries.
5. Time the effect of your meddling with indexes **on a regular basis**. A forced index that speeds up your query today might slow it down tomorrow because the underlying data has changed.

Comment: thanks, but I got similar results wiht inner join. Maybe I'd need to create subqueries somehow. Or increase the cache time to 1 day :)

Comment: I've forced the index, but the same result

Comment: Forcing the index does not guarantee that MySQL will **use** an index, it will just force MySQL to use a **different** index than the one it wants to use. If MySQL does not see any indexes forcing an index will usually do nothing. MySQL already has an overwhelming urge to use indexes anyway.